# Apache drill version 1.18 1.19 issue

Tags: java, jdbc, apache-drill

I recently discovered this blocker in apache drill 1.18 and found that it's there in drill 1.19 as well. Whenever you try to execute any query in drill, it will first create all the existing storage plugins. Now, if I had added a plugin before for a database whose IP has now changed (or any connection property), it won't be able to connect and will keep the query in the planning stage for a long time. Does anyone know any resolution to this or on how we can work around this? Any help or links would be greatly appreciated. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

> Whenever you try to execute any query in drill, it will first create all the existing storage plugins.

That's not correct. The storage drivers are update after drill startup - or - when **you** update them via the web UI.

> a database whose IP has now changed

Having a database which changes it's IP is a major design flaw, not a drill failure. If the db is under your governance, I'd recommend you to fix the IP. Otherwise you have to go to Drill Web UI, section `Storage`, then find your plugin and update the address by your needs, every time the IP is changed. There is [official docs](https://drill.apache.org/docs/rdbms-storage-plugin/) for that.